# How to troubleshoot when project is never up-to-date?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, incremental-build

Here's what I see in Build tab of Output window no matter how many times I rebuild the project:

```
------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
MainResourcesGeneration:
Skipping target "MainResourcesGeneration" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreResGen:
  No resources are out of date with respect to their source files. Skipping resource generation.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory:
Skipping target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CopyAppConfigFile:
Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  MyProject -> C:\MySolution\MyProject\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject.dll

Build succeeded.

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 666 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why does the `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` target always execute?

*Details:*

Visual Studio 2013 Update 5

.NET Framework 4.6.1

MSBuild 4.6.1055.0

Build output verbosity set to Normal

No pre-build or post-build steps

Parallel project builds are off (max number set to 1)